# Where exactly does backer board need to reside in a bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, backer-board

I'm a little confused on where exactly backer board needs to reside in a bathroom.  I know it needs to immediately cover the walls that the shower/bathtub face, but what about the rest of the walls in the bathroom? Is backer board needed *everywhere* in a bathroom?

Comment: It's not needed everywhere, but it's far more robust than drywall. It does cost a bit more, but most bathrooms are not that large. But that's entirely up to you. I lean to the "tile the whole bathroom anyway" side of the scale, having torn out too many rotten bits in the other kind of bathroom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backer board, [HardieBacker](http://www.jameshardie.com/homeowner/products-interior.shtml), or cement board is used on any surface that is to be tiled.

Comment: So conversely, in areas where I'm NOT tiling, I don't necessarily need to put backer board down... right?

Comment: Exactly, what you do want is moisture resistant plasterboard and it wouldn't hurt to use one of the newer mold resistant non-paper faced types.

Comment: Sorry - one more question: does backer board go ON TOP of drywall?  Or just over the bare walls with a moisture barrier in between?

Comment: @MikeB It can go directly on the wall, you'll just use a thicker board (1/2", 5/8", etc.). Or it can go over existing drywall, just user thinner stuff (1/4"). If the walls are uncovered now, I'd just use backer board.